# QGIS 3.12.3: V.to.3d: Number of centroids exceeds number of areas

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, 3d

QGIS.3.12.3 | CRS = WGS 84 | Grass downloaded

Making a habitat survey map 3d using height values stored in attribute using v.to.3d.

Parameters

```
Name of vector map: Habitat layer  
Input feature type: 4 options selected (I have also just tried centroids) 
Name of attribute col: Height 
v.in.ogr snap: default: -1 
v.in.ogr min area: default 0.000100 
v.out.ogr output: auto
```

This is the result:

```
QGIS version: 3.12.3-București
QGIS code revision: 8234261527
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.to.3d' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-r' : False, '-t' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'column' : 'Height', 'height' : None, 'input' : 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/LakeProject/Habitats.shp', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'type' : [0,1,2,3] }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=0.0 input="C:\Users\user\Desktop\LakeProject\Habitats.shp" output="vector_6077319cec8a612" --overwrite -o
g.region n=37.78757493408765 s=37.786860653618696 e=-122.46628277404538 w=-122.46736208177902
v.to.3d input=vector_6077319cec8a612 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Height output=outputbf3bedccc3554cfea0c60550cb3c5a71 --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="outputbf3bedccc3554cfea0c60550cb3c5a71" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rRZEYa\bf4d428cde154eb39dc9db7aaad1a1f9\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
The system cannot find the file C:\rtools40\Version.txt.
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rRZEYa\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\user\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\user\Documents>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=0.0 input="C:\Users\user\Desktop\LakeProject\Habitats.shp" output="vector_6077319cec8a612" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <Habitats> contains polygons...
0..3..5..7..9..12..14..16..18..20..23..25..27..29..32..34..36..38..40..43..45..47..49..52..54..56..58..60..63..65..67..69..72..74..76..78..80..83..85..87..89..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <Habitats>...
Column name <Common nam> renamed to <Common_nam>
Column name <Species na> renamed to <Species_na>
Column name <Native?> renamed to <Native_>
Importing 55 features (OGR layer <Habitats>)...
0..3..5..7..9..12..14..16..18..20..23..25..27..29..32..34..36..38..40..43..45..47..49..52..54..56..58..60..63..65..67..69..72..74..76..78..80..83..85..87..89..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning polygons
-----------------------------------------------------
Snapping boundaries (threshold = 0.000e+000)...
Reading features...
Snap vertices Pass 1: select points
0..3..7..10..14..17..21..24..28..31..35..38..42..45..49..52..56..59..63..66..70..73..77..80..84..87..91..94..98..100
Snap vertices Pass 2: assign anchor vertices
4..9..14..19..24..29..34..39..44..49..54..59..64..69..74..79..84..89..94..99..100
Snap vertices Pass 3: snap to assigned points
0..3..7..10..14..17..21..24..28..31..35..38..42..45..49..52..56..59..63..66..70..73..77..80..84..87..91..94..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking polygons...
Breaking polygons (pass 1: select break points)...
1..3..5..7..10..12..14..17..19..21..24..26..28..31..33..35..38..40..42..45..47..49..52..54..56..59..61..63..66..68..70..73..75..77..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
Breaking polygons (pass 2: break at selected points)...
1..3..5..7..10..12..14..17..19..21..24..26..28..31..33..35..38..40..42..45..47..49..52..54..56..59..61..63..66..68..70..73..75..77..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging boundaries...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing dangles...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..-----------------------------------------------------
Removing bridges...
38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..25..50..75..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Finding centroids for OGR layer <Habitats>...
0..3..7..10..14..18..21..25..29..32..36..40..43..47..50..54..58..61..65..69..72..76..80..83..87..90..94..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Writing centroids...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
56 input polygons
Total area: 3101.68 (100 areas)
Overlapping area: 5.079 (28 areas)
Area without category: 0.487711 (15 areas)
-----------------------------------------------------
Copying features...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Building topology for vector map <vector_6077319cec8a612@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..25..50..75..100
Attaching centroids...
0..2..4..7..9..11..14..16..18..20..22..24..27..29..31..34..36..38..40..42..44..47..49..51..54..56..58..60..62..64..67..69..71..74..76..78..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
28 areas represent multiple (overlapping) features, because polygons overlap in input layer(s). Such areas are linked to more than 1 row in attribute table. The number of features for those areas is stored as category in layer 2
-----------------------------------------------------
If overlapping is not desired, the input data can be cleaned by snapping vertices to each other.
Estimated range of snapping threshold: [1e-013, 0.0001]
C:\Users\user\Documents>g.region n=37.78757493408765 s=37.786860653618696 e=-122.46628277404538 w=-122.46736208177902
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.to.3d input=vector_6077319cec8a612 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Height output=outputbf3bedccc3554cfea0c60550cb3c5a71 --overwrite
Fetching height from <Height> column...
Transforming features...
Copying attributes...
Building topology for vector map <outputbf3bedccc3554cfea0c60550cb3c5a71@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
WARNING: Number of centroids exceeds number of areas: 85 > 0
WARNING: Number of centroids outside area: 85
Vertical extent of vector map <outputbf3bedccc3554cfea0c60550cb3c5a71>: B: 1.000000 T: 200.000000
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="outputbf3bedccc3554cfea0c60550cb3c5a71" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rRZEYa\bf4d428cde154eb39dc9db7aaad1a1f9\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
WARNING: Unable to determine input map's vector feature type(s).
WARNING: 85 centroids found, but not requested to be exported. Verify 'type' parameter.
WARNING: Vector map <outputbf3bedccc3554cfea0c60550cb3c5a71> is 3D. Use format specific layer creation options (parameter 'lco') to export <in 3D rather than 2D (default).
WARNING: Output layer is empty, no features written
v.out.ogr complete. 0 features (Unknown (any) type) written to <outputbf3bedccc3554cfea0c60550cb3c5a71> (GPKG format).
C:\Users\user\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rRZEYa\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 14.36 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'v.to.3d' finished
QGIS version: 3.12.3-București
QGIS code revision: 8234261527
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.to.3d' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-r' : False, '-t' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'column' : 'Height', 'height' : None, 'input' : 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/LakeProject/Habitats.shp', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'type' : [0,1,2,3] }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\user\Desktop\LakeProject\Habitats.shp" output="vector_607732ab714b813" --overwrite -o
g.region n=37.78757493408765 s=37.786860653618696 e=-122.46628277404538 w=-122.46736208177902
v.to.3d input=vector_607732ab714b813 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Height output=output405740aafb2a4f03a268459140e45c82 --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output405740aafb2a4f03a268459140e45c82" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rRZEYa\58d6ab6b7fcf4aefa62abdd04a92344a\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
The system cannot find the file C:\rtools40\Version.txt.
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rRZEYa\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\user\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\user\Documents>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\user\Desktop\LakeProject\Habitats.shp" output="vector_607732ab714b813" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <Habitats> contains polygons...
0..3..5..7..9..12..14..16..18..20..23..25..27..29..32..34..36..38..40..43..45..47..49..52..54..56..58..60..63..65..67..69..72..74..76..78..80..83..85..87..89..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <Habitats>...
Column name <Common nam> renamed to <Common_nam>
Column name <Species na> renamed to <Species_na>
Column name <Native?> renamed to <Native_>
Importing 55 features (OGR layer <Habitats>)...
0..3..5..7..9..12..14..16..18..20..23..25..27..29..32..34..36..38..40..43..45..47..49..52..54..56..58..60..63..65..67..69..72..74..76..78..80..83..85..87..89..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning polygons
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking polygons...
Breaking polygons (pass 1: select break points)...
1..3..5..7..10..12..14..17..19..21..24..26..28..31..33..35..38..40..42..45..47..49..52..54..56..59..61..63..66..68..70..73..75..77..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
Breaking polygons (pass 2: break at selected points)...
1..3..5..7..10..12..14..17..19..21..24..26..28..31..33..35..38..40..42..45..47..49..52..54..56..59..61..63..66..68..70..73..75..77..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging boundaries...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing dangles...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..-----------------------------------------------------
Removing bridges...
38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..25..50..75..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Finding centroids for OGR layer <Habitats>...
0..3..7..10..14..18..21..25..29..32..36..40..43..47..50..54..58..61..65..69..72..76..80..83..87..90..94..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Writing centroids...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
56 input polygons
Total area: 3101.68 (100 areas)
Overlapping area: 5.079 (28 areas)
Area without category: 0.487711 (15 areas)
-----------------------------------------------------
Copying features...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Building topology for vector map <vector_607732ab714b813@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..25..50..75..100
Attaching centroids...
0..2..4..7..9..11..14..16..18..20..22..24..27..29..31..34..36..38..40..42..44..47..49..51..54..56..58..60..62..64..67..69..71..74..76..78..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
28 areas represent multiple (overlapping) features, because polygons overlap in input layer(s). Such areas are linked to more than 1 row in attribute table. The number of features for those areas is stored as category in layer 2
-----------------------------------------------------
If overlapping is not desired, the input data can be cleaned by snapping vertices to each other.
Estimated range of snapping threshold: [1e-013, 0.0001]
C:\Users\user\Documents>g.region n=37.78757493408765 s=37.786860653618696 e=-122.46628277404538 w=-122.46736208177902
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.to.3d input=vector_607732ab714b813 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Height output=output405740aafb2a4f03a268459140e45c82 --overwrite
Fetching height from <Height> column...
Transforming features...
Copying attributes...
Building topology for vector map <output405740aafb2a4f03a268459140e45c82@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
WARNING: Number of centroids exceeds number of areas: 85 > 0
WARNING: Number of centroids outside area: 85
Vertical extent of vector map <output405740aafb2a4f03a268459140e45c82>: B: 1.000000 T: 200.000000
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output405740aafb2a4f03a268459140e45c82" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rRZEYa\58d6ab6b7fcf4aefa62abdd04a92344a\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
WARNING: Unable to determine input map's vector feature type(s).
WARNING: 85 centroids found, but not requested to be exported. Verify 'type' parameter.
WARNING: Vector map <output405740aafb2a4f03a268459140e45c82> is 3D. Use format specific layer creation options (parameter 'lco') to export <in 3D rather than 2D (default).
WARNING: Output layer is empty, no features written
v.out.ogr complete. 0 features (Unknown (any) type) written to <output405740aafb2a4f03a268459140e45c82> (GPKG format).
C:\Users\user\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rRZEYa\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 8.06 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'v.to.3d' finished
```

It seems unable to determine the maps feature type. As well as centroids exceeding number of areas.

I have used check validity to see if the polygons are valid, I have also snapped the areas within the layer so there are no overlays/overshoots.

I am running this inside QGIS, I have never produced a 3d before.